# SSIS challenges and small projects

Tags: ssis, project

I have done some searching on the web for challenges and small projects, that will be great to have for people who are learning SSIS(Sql Server Integration Services) but could not find any.

So,Anyone has a suggestions of sites that could have SSIS challenges, that can be helpful for people who are learning it?

Or you could also post challenges that you have that you would love to share

Comment: Thank you Siva for the suggestion , i will take a look at them

Answer (score 0):

here are a few links depending on you current ssis level

[Creating a Simple ETL Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx)

[Beyond basics of SSIS](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tutorial/Tutorial-SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-best-practices#Beyond)

[Advanced_SSIS_Package_Design_Tutorial](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Advanced_SSIS_Package_Design_Tutorial)